# Was ist das Gegenteil davon einen Zonk zu erwischen?

Tags: idiom, colloquial

Wenn man "*den Zonk erwischt*", ist dies Ausdruck dafür ein schlimmstmögliches Ergebnis erzielt zu haben. Was wäre das sprachliche Gegenteil des Zonks?

Answer (score 2):

Der [Zonk](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonk) stammt aus der Fernsehserie *Geh aufs Ganze!* und war dort das Synonym für eine Niete. *Den Zonk ziehen* hat sich als Sprichwort für *Pech haben* eingebürgert.

Als Gegenteil für den *Zonk* selbst könnte man jetzt zum Beispiel einen *Sechser im Lotto* anführen. Das Gegenteil zum Sprichwort wäre dann *Einen Sechser im Lotto haben*.

Das ist natürlich nur ein Beispiel. Es gibt sicher viele andere Beispiele für Sprichworte, die sich als Synonym für *Glück haben* nutzen lassen.

Answer (score 2):

Dann werfe ich mal meinen Ansatz in den Topf.

Der Zonk ist wie in der Antwort von Aschratt erwähnt auch als Synonym für eine "Niete" zu sehen.

Treffendes Gegenstück wäre also:

> Das große Los ziehen

Comment: Oder "Den Hauptgewinn" - neben den anderen Antworten die auch nicht schlecht sind.

Answer (score 1):

Wie bereits in der anderen Antwort gegeben, erwischte man wortwörtlich den Zonk, wenn man in der Fernsehserie eine falsche Entscheidung getroffen hat, genau genommen, wenn man sich für das falsche Tor oder für den falschen Umschlag entschieden hat.

Mir kommt kein Sprichtwort in den Sinn, wo man "das richtige Tor" oder "den richtigen Umschlag" wählt, aber was meiner Meinung nach am nächsten kommt, ist:

> aufs richtige Pferd setzen

<sub>Andererseits ist das Gegenteil dazu wiederum *aufs falsche Pferd setzen*.</sub>

Comment: Der qualitative Unterschied scheint mir, dass "den Zonk zu erwischen/ziehen" etwas ist was vollkommen vom Glück abhängt, während auf ein Pferd zu setzen (im sprichwörtlichen Sinn) nicht ein Indiz für *reines* Glück ist, sondern eher für richtiges Kalkül (ggf. mit einer kleine Prise Glück dabei).

Comment: @bitmask Das stimmt wohl. Andererseits, wenn man einen guten Riecher hat, konnte man seine Chancen auf einen Gewinn bestimmt erhöhen ;)